# Django dependent dropdown with Ajax problems with ids

Tags: django, ajax, dropdown

I am trying to implement a dependent dropdown. Vitor Freitas did this in his blog and I am basically following his [solution](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html). 
(A really cool blog with clear code which helped me a lot of times).

I have adopted it to my pages but it stuck exactly where the dropdown should be restricted. I am pretty sure that I messed up with the foreign key or with Ajax/javascript (as I have no clue about ajax+javascript.)

Maybe you see my 'basic' error and can help me. Would be thankful.

**models.py**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Provider(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomerSubsidiary(models.Model):
    subCountry = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('test', views.CustomerSubsidiaryListView.as_view(), name='CustomerSubsidiary_changelist'),
    path('test/add/', views.CustomerSubsidiaryCreateView.as_view(), name='CustomerSubsidiary_add'),
    path('test/<int:pk>/', views.CustomerSubsidiaryUpdateView.as_view(), name='CustomerSubsidiary_change'),
    path('ajax/load-provider/', views.load_provider, name='ajax_load_provider'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def load_provider(request):
    country_id = request.GET.get('country')
    provider = Provider.objects.filter(country_id=country_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'Customer/city_dropdown_list_options.html', {'provider': provider})
```

**providerForm**

```
class ProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerSubsidiary
        fields = ('subName', 'subCountry', 'provider')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['provider'].queryset = Provider.objects.none()
```

**customersubsidiary_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <h2>Provider Form</h2>

  <form method="post" id="providerForm" data-provider-url="{% url 'ajax_load_provider' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <a href="{% url 'CustomerSubsidiary_changelist' %}">Nevermind</a>
  </form>




  <script>
    $("#id_country").change(function () {
      var url = $("#providerForm").attr("data-provider-url");  
      var countryId = $(this).val();  

      $.ajax({                       
        url: url,                    
        data: {
          'country': countryId       
        },
        success: function (data) { 
          $("#id_provider").html(data);  
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

The jquery is loaded in the base.html.

**city_dropdown_list_options.html**

```
<option value="">-------</option>
{% for providers in provider %}
<option value="{{ providers.pk }}">{{ providers.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006988/ajax-request-not-working-properly-in-django/51009944#51009944

Comment: what is not working? describe your problem and update error logs in question if any

Comment: @Wariored: When I get th post right, I have to initialise or set up CSRF when using Ajax?!

Comment: @Satendra: The Webform works fine, that means you see the countries to choose, but you don't see a provider. I have added some via the admin page. You only see at the provider the Option "-------" as stated above in the city_dropdown...html. 
When I write in the views:  provider = Provider.objects.all() then the ajax loader page shows me correctly the existing providers. So the filter/join with the ids in the views doesn't work properly in my eyes.

Comment: do you have `id_provider ` in your HTML, where you are appending response data, I hope you are getting the correct response from API, open inspect tool and check the `id` of the second dropdown and replace that id in place of  `id_provider` that you are using in ajax success

Comment: I solved it: I look in the source code of the html and saw that the id in the form was id_subCountry. Accordingly I had to change the code in the AJAX script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw in the source code of the page that the names for the Ids where wrong that means they did not match to views.py.

In **views.py** it should be:

```
def load_provider(request):
    country_id = request.GET.get('subCountry') #<-- change country to subCountry, that means the attribute name of the original class
```

In the **ajax-script** change the id to #id_subCountry and change country to subCountry:

```
<script>
    $("#id_subCountry").change(function () {
      var url = $("#providerForm").attr("data-provider-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
      var subCountryId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
          'subCountry': subCountryId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
          $("#id_provider").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here: self.fields['provider'].queryset = Provider.objects.**none()**. When you add the data from "request.POST" in the form field "provider" will always be " none". Try removing this line from your code or adding it:

**views.py/edit**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        ProviderForm.request_change=True

        form = ProviderForm(request.POST)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):
request_change=False

class Meta:
    model = CustomerSubsidiary
    fields = ('subName', 'subCountry', 'provider')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if request_change:
        request_change=False
    else:
        self.fields['provider'].queryset = Provider.objects.none()
```

Comment: And $("#id_country").change(function () replace $("#id_subCountry").change(function ()

Comment: Please don't add information to your answer in comments. Instead, use the `edit` link under your post to add the information to the post.